# can we drag and drop a field in vf page

Tags: page-layout

i had created a vf page and configured with Account New button.Now,using page layout,can i add fields in vf page,

or

is there any way,if Account field is created,that field must be updated in Account__C(replica object)

need help,thanks in advance

Comment: So, as I understand when you click on the 'New' button on your account, this VF page opens. now you want your page layout to be available? you cannot do  that, what are exactly your requirements?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click new account? and what is the flow of your requirement?

Comment: if i create a field of Account (standard object) from UI,same field has to be created in replica object.

Comment: Am afraid that is not possible,we cannot create custom fields on a Custom Object on creation of a Field in Account Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No thats not possible from standard layout. Because SF does not allow any trigger on Metadata so you can't automate this process.

But using Metadata API you can complete this approach. Create a Page where your users fill all required information and then From there you can create two fields one on Standard Object  and another one is on your custom object.

There is very Good [Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) which you can use as starting point

Code sample from the same

```
public static void createField()
    {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestField__c';
        customField.label = 'Test Field';
        customField.type_x = 'Text';
        customField.length = 42;
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =      
            service.createMetadata(
                new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });                
        handleSaveResults(results[0]);
    }
```

Comment: can i write this logic in batch class to create fields

Comment: @sasfdc yes you can.

Comment: in start method,i have to pass which or what field i have to create.correct.and execute method?!

Comment: can u please give input to start the requirement.

Comment: @sasfdc I think you need to check how to write the batch. If you stuck somewhere then you can ask a separate question.